# Close the workbook after saving it

Tags: excel, vba

I run the macro from another workbook, as i generate daily reports, i already save them but i want to close them after saving them, i tried with ThisWorkbook.Close and ThisActiveWorkbook.Close it just stops the loop from the macro and it doesn't close the workbook.

Here is my code:

```
Dim IntialName As String
Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
IntialName = "Sample"
sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, filefilter:="Workbook(*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If sFileSaveName <> False Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName, FileFormat:=51
End If

End With
xFileName = Dir
Loop
End If
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook` is the workbook with the code in it, not the one you want to close.

`ThisActiveWorkbook` is nothing at all.

Use:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```